# Basic c++ code problems

Tags: c++, windows, graphics

I need some help with some C++ code. I'm trying to make a program where the word up goes up and down goes down the screen. I want it to do this 3 times. My program is successful where the words do what I want them to do. However, it does not do it 3 times. I put it in a for loop, so I'm not sure what is wrong. I'm learning, so I just need help understanding what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    COORD posUp = {5,25}; 
    COORD posDown = {68,1}; 

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posUp); 
    cout<<"Up"<<endl; 
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posDown); 
    cout<< "Down"<<endl; 
    Sleep(400); 
    for(int comeback=1; comeback<=3; comeback++) { 
        while(posUp.Y > 1 && posDown.Y < 24) { 
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen,posUp); 
            cout<<" "<<endl; 
            posUp.Y--; 
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posUp); 
            cout<<"Up"<<endl; 
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posDown); 
            cout<<" "; 
            posDown.Y++; 
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posDown); 
            cout<<"Down"<<endl; 
            Sleep(100); 
        } 

        SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posUp); 
        cout<<" "<<endl; 
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posDown); 
        cout<< " "<<endl; 
        Sleep(100); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Consider the value of `posUp.Y` the second time around the outer loop. What will that do to your inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like your decrementing posUp and incrementing posDown in the while loop but not resetting the values at the end of the for loop.

```
for(int comeback=1; comeback<=3; comeback++) { 
    while(posUp.Y > 1 && posDown.Y < 24) { 
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen,posUp); 
        cout<<" "<<endl; 
        posUp.Y--; 
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posUp); 
        cout<<"Up"<<endl; 
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posDown); 
        cout<<" "; 
        posDown.Y++; 
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posDown); 
        cout<<"Down"<<endl; 
        Sleep(100); 
    } 

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posUp); 
    cout<<" "<<endl; 
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, posDown); 
    cout<< " "<<endl; 
    posUp = {5,25}; 
    posDown = {68,1}; 
    Sleep(100); 
}
```

Comment: Now I understand. That makes sense why it didn't repeat.